# Get CultureInfo used in Windows Clock

Tags: c#, windows, calendar, operating-system, cultureinfo

I am trying to find a way to get `CultureInfo` of that is used by the operating system - Windows - for the clock.

[image]

[image]

My system is `en-US`, but my calendar uses `de-DE` formats, but when I check the following properties, all of them show me `en-US`

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture
CurrentInfo.InstalledUICulture
```

Is there any way to get the `CultureInfo` used by the operating system - Windows - clock?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "for the calendar"? Where exactly have you set this on your system?

Comment: Maybe your calender has an option of culture itself and overrides these values?

Comment: The system clock is using German format, but my system is installed in English. I am trying to find a way how to get the cultureinfo used by the system clock.

Comment: @SonerGönül It is not a problem that the system clock is in German. I am working on an excel addIn and I need to show in some WPF forms datetime values formatted with the system clock culture, instead of the current thread, installed...

Comment: UI Language of your Windows?

Comment: @DrKoch As I mentioned, UI of my windows is in `en-US`. Only the system clock is using the `de-DE` . All the CultureInfo.*  properties I tried show `en-US`.

Comment: Could you override culture of  calender ?  With this option you can control the calender format, maybe you can take culture info from other components.

Comment: @AhmetArslan I don't want/need to override any format. I just need to know what is the cultureinfo used by the system clock.

Comment: Why does your clock use the `de-DE` format? Which setting did you change? Language, and Region-> Regional and Language -> Format?

Comment: @sloth Yes, I changed the format in the region and language settings.

Comment: When you set the format to __German (Germany)__ in the dialog box in your screen shot you should see that `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` reflects this setting. In addition, if you perform further customizations of the format as you can do in the dialog box these changes will be reflected in `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`. However, the format setting is a user setting so if your process run as another user then you will get `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` for that user - not your own setting. That might explain the discrepancy you experience.

Comment: To add to my previous comment: I believe your mistake is referring to the __system__ calendar. There is no system calendar. Instead each user is able to select a personal culture for date and time formatting. However, the initial culture used for new user accounts can be modified in the __Administrative__ tab on the dialog box of your screen shot.

Comment: @MartinLiversage Thanks for the explanation. And could it be possible to access to these personal settings?

Comment: @blacai: Sure you can if you are determined enough. The setting is stored somewhere on the computer. But if my hypothesis is true and your application run as another user (perhaps as a service?) do you want to create code that inside this service accesses your user profile to get your personal setting? What if the application runs on another computer where you do not have a user profile? Perhaps you should rethink your problem to figure out what it really is you want to achieve?